# GitHub - PR request

Tags: github

There is a new feature needed and I did following: Forked whole repo to my personal repo. Now I know how to do a change in a code but should I:

1. Create a new branch and submit a code to a new branch and then do PR
   or
2. Do changes on a Master (in my personal forked repo) and then
   submit a PR?

Asking because in both scenarios there is going to be someone doing LGTM but not sure should I create a new branch or work on my forked master?

Comment: Please consult the person with whom you will be merging to see if they care. This is not possible to answer definitively on GitHub. It is almost exclusively based on how you like to work and/or how your team likes to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference. From the point of view of original repo, your `master` is just a regular non-master branch.

Comment: Ok, but what happens when someone lgtm my local master? Does it get merged with master of original repo or it goes to some branch?

Comment: @Joe when you create PR, you specify both source branch and destination branch. You may create PR into theirs `master` branch or `unstable` branch or whatever topic branch. If you specify wrong destination branch, project maintainers will ask you to change it